# What's so special about the grounded poset of cardinality $2$?

Tags: category-theory, definition, order-theory, higher-category-theory, universal-property

By a *grounded poset*, I mean a poset $P$ with a bottom element $0_P$. Arrows between grounded posets are monotone mappings that preserve the basepoint. This gives a self-enriched category; lets call it $\mathbf{GPos}$. Okay, now let $J$ denote the grounded poset with two elements. Explicitly: $$J = \{1,0\}, \qquad 1_J > 0_J$$

Then $J$ satisfies the following "universal" property: for all grounded posets $X$, there is a maximum arrow $X \rightarrow J$. In particular, this is the mapping that takes every element of $X$ to $1_J$, except for $0_X$ which is mapped to $0_J$.

Unfortunately, this "universal" property doesn't characterize $J$, not even close, because every grounded poset with a maximum element satisfies this same property! So what I'm looking for is a strengthening of the aforementioned "universal" property. It should:

- characterize $J$ as an object of $\mathbf{GPos}.$
- make sense in any $\mathbf{Pos}$-enriched category, or at least in any $\mathbf{GPos}$-enriched category.
- determine objects up to isomorphism; meaning that if $\mathbf{C}$ is a $\mathbf{GPos}$-enriched category, then it should be provable that any two objects of $\mathbf{C}$ satisfying this property are isomorphic.

Comment: What's the context here, i.e. why should this object be special in $\mathbf{GPos}$, other than the property that you mention?

Comment: @CliveNewstead, the maximum arrow $f_X : X \rightarrow J$ behaves exactly like the "not-bottom element predicate"; in the sense that $f_X(x)=1$ iff $x$ is not the bottom element. The interesting thing is that $J$ is, in some sense, the smallest object of $\mathbf{GPos}$ that can play this role. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a $\mathbf{Pos}$-enriched category $\mathcal{C}$ and an object $Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, a **downward-closed subobject** of $Y$ is a monomorphism $m : X \to Y$  in $\mathcal{C}$ such that, for every object $T$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the induced map
$$\mathcal{C} (T, m) : \mathcal{C} (T, X) \to \mathcal{C} (T, Y)$$
is the embedding of a downward-closed subset.

In the case where $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{Pos}$ or $\mathcal{C} = \mathbf{GPos}$, this coincides with the usual notion, and it is easy to see that $J$ classifies downward-closed subobjects in those cases. This is a universal property that characterises $J$ up to isomorphism.